# AIX kernel internal stats of nmon: fork vs exec

Tags: aix, process-management, exec, fork

Why the values of fork and exec stats shown on the kernel internal stats of nmon utility in AIX systems (k option) are so different?

Usually the shown fork value is greater than the exec value, varying from 30% to 100% greater, it's rarely smaller, but it happends too.

Shouldn't they be the same or almost the same value along time? Are there ways to track which processes are being forked and executed?

Comment: running from a shell `nohup nice sleep 1` would generate one fork and 3 exec. Now an apache httpd server  (pre-fork mode) would generate probably mostly forks, since httpd only has to fork to create/recycle "workers".

Comment: So, I bet that external calls using `system()` would call `exec` at least twice. Right?

Comment: probably (sh + actual command, along the initial fork *and* the command fork too). Now I don't have any particular knowledge on AIX tools to track this. It would probably fall in the umbrella of process accounting and auditing

Comment: Your comment actually answered the question, thanks.